# How to define an Initializer for GA1DArrayGenome<float> in GALib?

Tags: c++, namespaces, genetic-algorithm, galib

I am using the GA1DArrayGenome class in the GALib2.4 Genetic Library. My aim is to optimize a list of 6 floating point numbers, so chromosomes should be something like [0.3 0.5 0.1 0.2 0.4 0.1], [0.03 0.04 0.1 0.2 0.05 0.8]...

I have trouble initializing the population, since after calling the GASimpleGA::evolve(), I found that whatever random seed I used, the genes of every chromosome are [0 0 0 0 0 0].

I checked the documentation and found that for GA1DArrayGenome class, the default Initializer is a GAGenome::NoInitializer, which, I assume, means I have to find another initializer for this genome class?

```
void main() {
// ...
GARandomSeed(1);
GA1DArrayGenome<float> genome(6, &Objective);
genome.initializer(/* ?? */);

GASimpleGA ga(genome);
ga.populationSize(100);
ga.nGenerations(100);
ga.pMutation(0.001);
ga.pCrossover(0.6);
ga.evolve();
cout << ga.statistics().bestIndividual() << endl;
// ...
}
```

The above is a procedure I use the GALib. It imitates what was done in the sample code ex27.C together with the library. However, the sample was doing something like

```
  // ...
  GA1DArrayGenome<float> genome(2, Objective);
  genome.initializer(::Initializer);
  genome.mutator(::Mutator);
  genome.comparator(::Comparator);
  genome.crossover(::Crossover);
  // ...
```

I don't quite get what it means by using no namespace before '::'.

Can someone help me on this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### Namespaces

The `::Foo` without a namespace in front means that the `Foo` declared in the global namespace (i.e. no namespace) is selected. Use this to "escape" from your current namespace back into global space. Another example would be `::std::string`, i.e. the `string` class in the `std` namespace that must not be nested.

### Initializers

`GA1DArrayGenome<T>` is very generic and doesn't know a thing about `T`. It doesn't know about acceptable values nor how to work on those values. Therefore you need to supply initializers, mutators, etc. If you just want "out of the box" `float` optimization, consider using the [derived class `GARealGenome` that comes with good defaults](http://lancet.mit.edu/galib-2.4/API.html#genome_real). See example 21 on the GALib page for demo code.